# How can I find which column contains the same value as another specified column in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with only one row. How can I find which column contains the same value as another specified column in the same dataframe?

For example, I want to find which flavour is the favorite flavor in this df. The answer should be the column name `flavour2` since it coincides with `'Apple'`:

```
df <- data.frame(flavour1 = c("Grape"),
                 flavour2 = c("Apple"),
                 flavour3 = c("Strawberry"),
                 favourite = c("Apple"))
```

Thank you!

Comment: This also might work: `colnames(df)[grep(df$favourite, df[1:3])]` The output: `[1] "flavour2"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check which column has the same value as `favourite`, this might do the trick:

```
colnames(df)[grep(df$favourite, df[1:3])]
```

Output:

```
> colnames(df)[grep(df$favourite, df[1:3])]
[1] "flavour2"
```

`grep(df$favourite, df[1:3])` returns the column index of `df[1:3]` that matches the value of `df$favourite`. Then, using this index, `colnames(df)[]` select the right column name.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare all the values in `df` with `favourite` column and return the corresponding column name.

```
names(which(df$favourite == unlist(df[-ncol(df)])))
#[1] "flavour2"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use

```
names(df)[df$favourite == df[-length(df)]]
#[1] "flavour2"
```

---

Or using `match`

```
names(df)[match(df$favourite, unlist(df[-length(df)]))]
#[1] "flavour2"
```